# object *operator<<(object* one, type& two);

Tags: c++, pointers, operator-overloading

**Original XY Problem Question**

I'm in the situation where I need to use the `object& operator<<(object& one, type& two);` operator overload, with the tweak of using pointers instead of references as below

```
object *operator<<(object* one, type& two);
```

The reason is my copy constructors and assignment operators are deleted because I am implementing an object similar to cout and cin. What's a neat hack to do this? I might go with windows API style code where I would define a `class pObject;` which is a class wrapper for a pointer to the object, but I want to know if there's a more elegant way.

**More Generic**

I have the following code where `T` and `T'` and distinct data types:

```
// foobar.h
namespace foo {
    class bar;
    extern foo::bar bExt;
}

foo::bar *operator<<(foo::bar *, T&);

namespace foo {
    class bar {
    public:
        static foo::bar *GetBar() { return new foo::bar; }
        void doSomething(T &t) {/* uses member variable mvar.*/}
    private:
        T' mvar; 
        friend foo::bar *::operator<<(foo::bar *, T &);
        bar() {/*initialize mvar appropriately*/} // default constructor

        bar(foo::bar const&) = delete;
        void operator=(foo::bar const&) = delete;
    };

}

//foobar.cpp
#include "foobar.h"

    foo::bar *foo::bExt = GetBar();
    foo::bar *operator<<(foo::bar *b, T&)
    {
        b->doSomething(T);
        return b;
    }

// main.cpp
#include "foobar.h"
int main()
{
    T x = /*something*/;
    foo::bExt << x; 
}
```

What I am hoping for is that the user will not be able to create an instance of `bar` or modify the `foo::bExt`, which is not a constant because `doSomething()` modifies it. Finally, I need a way to do it all while still allowing for the operator overload `object& operator<<(object& one, type& two);` which has been incorrectly used above.

**Further Clarification**

The code posted below this paragraph will not compile because the copy constructor and assignment operator have been deleted. However, this is the exact format my code requires because one way or the other the extern variable `foo::bExt` needs to be defined via some complicated constructor procedure and then used as an argument to the overload operator similar to the appearance and use of `std::cout`. The quick workaround is to to define a `extern foo::bar *` object, as has been stated in the code above this paragraph, and use the pointer as the argument to the operator. A quick fix is is to dereference the now pointer extern object `*foo::bExt` every time the `operator<<` is invoked with it as argument, but no one does `*std::cout << 1;` so nor should they `*foo::bExt << 1;`. It seems cumbersome and inelegant, and at least warrants an investigation for an alternative. Hence my question. Don't just take my word for it, try the below code with

`g++ -std=c++11 <name>.cpp -o <name>`

```
#include <iostream>

namespace foo
{
    class bar;
    extern foo::bar bExt;
}

foo::bar &operator<<(foo::bar& ,int&);

namespace foo
{

    class bar
    {
    public:
        static foo::bar GetBar()
        { 
            static foo::bar temp;
            return temp; 
        }
        void print() {std::cout << v << std::endl;}
    private:
        int v;
        bar() : v(1965) {};
        friend foo::bar &::operator<<(foo::bar &, int&);

        /* Commenting out the below copy constructor and
         * assignment operator allows the code to compile.
         */
        bar(foo::bar const&) = delete;
        void operator=(foo::bar const&) = delete;
    };
    foo::bar bExt = foo::bar::GetBar();
}

foo::bar &operator<<(foo::bar &b, int &i)
{
    b.v += i;
    return b;
}

int main()
{
    int i = 50;
    foo::bExt << i;
    foo::bExt.print();
}
```

Comment: Your basis for not using references seems wrong.

Comment: @chris check the edit. At any rate, do you know how to overcome the primary problem?

Comment: Just don´t, it makes no sense. And currently I don´t see any solution for adding operators to pointers.

Comment: That's no reason to use pointers instead of references. And you cannot overload operators for built-in types (such as pointers).

Comment: What is the problem? The references do not need copy constructions or assignments. Please post example of the problem.

Comment: You mention `cout` and `cin` specifically. Those are almost always passed by reference.

Comment: Maybe my answer posted below will clarify what I intended.

Comment: This is quickly becoming a series of [XY problems](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You need to take a step back and rethink what you're trying to accomplish otherwise you're going to keep revisiting it more and more as your codebase grows.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious okidoke. I'm actually curious now as to what alternative, perhaps better solutions exist. I'll elaborate my question so check the edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As has been pointed out (no pun intended) in comments on your question, there is nothing wrong with using references; however, it appears that you don't understand why, so I will explain it.

References contain built-in constant pointers. This means that when you pass a reference to an object, neither the copy constructor nor the assignment operator are called on your object; rather, it is the reference's internal pointer that is copied over, and there is still only one copy of the object itself. For that reason, you can still use references to the object, even if the copy constructor and/or assignment operator are deleted.

I hope this helps you understand how references work.

**EDIT: actual full solution**

Here is an actual solution based on the second code block given in the question:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace foo
{
    class bar;
    extern foo::bar& bExt;
}

foo::bar &operator<<(foo::bar& ,int&);

namespace foo
{

    class bar
    {
    public:
        static foo::bar* GetBar()
        { 
            return new foo::bar();
        }
        void print() {std::cout << v << std::endl;}
    private:
        int v;
        bar() : v(1965) {};
        friend foo::bar&::operator<<(foo::bar&, int&);

        /* Commenting out the below copy constructor and
         * assignment operator allows the code to compile.
         */
        bar(foo::bar const&) = delete;
        void operator=(foo::bar const&) = delete;
    };
    foo::bar& bExt = *foo::bar::GetBar();
}

foo::bar &operator<<(foo::bar &b, int &i)
{
    b.v += i;
    return b;
}

int main()
{
    int i = 50;
    foo::bExt << i;
    foo::bExt.print();
}
```

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: I've edited the above main post. I'm afraid I haven't explained my question well enough so please take a look at the new edits. Your paragraph on references was a good refresher but nonetheless already understood. This particular situation I am in makes it difficult to use references so please look at the edit if you wish to know why.

Comment: @Sanfer can you do `extern foo::bar& bExt;` ?

Comment: wow you're right, I guess I don't know references that well. Ok, I'll mark your post as the correct answer as soon as you edit it and include an actual solution.

Comment: Actual solution is now in the answer @Sanfer

Answer (score -2):

Turns out the following overload does the trick:

```
object *& operator<<(object *& one, type& two);
```

Comment: You cannot overload operators with only builtin types. This will only work if `type` is a user-defined type.

Comment: @curiosguy `object` is a user-defined type. `type` may be a system type like `int`. Does the standard still prevent this?

Comment: You can't overload on pointer types, even when there is no built-in operator for pointer type (ptr << int is not valid).